# Problems when adding data into database (More data/parameters added)

Tags: c#, database

I have a database which i insert some data into. The problem i have is that it will add more data then it should.

When the logfordb.pos is increasing it will add all prevoius data one more time and next time it will add even more.

Here is the code... with some reduction of conn string and parametres.

```
    public void WriteToDatabase(DatabaseLog logfordb)
    {
        conn.Open();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO [X] (Y, Z, C " + "Values (@val1, @val2, @val3";

        for (int index = 0; index < logfordb.ListofDB[logfordb.pos].X.Count; index++)
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            if (logfordb.ListofDB[logfordb.pos].X[index].Details != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", logfordb.ListofDB[logfordb.pos].X[index].Details.Age);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", logfordb.ListofDB[logfordb.pos].X[index].Details.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", logfordb.ListofDB[logfordb.pos].X[index].Details.Etc);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();

        logfordb.pos += 1;
    }
```

Comment: How much data should it add? Obviously "pos += 1" is causing the problem.

Comment: It should add all findings in a list (ListofDB) where the pos is the index value of the list

Comment: You're always starting from zero in the for loop so you're adding all data again

Comment: also the  "Insert INTO [X] (Y, Z, C " + "Values (@val1, @val2, @val3"; isa missing a ) before Values

Comment: try changing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` to `cmd.Parameters.Add`. just curious to how that would affect it. as they accomplish the same thing

Comment: @EricRobinson the cmd.Parameters.Add dident add anything.

Comment: @AmiramKorach Yeah i should start from 0 at every new [index/logpos] if that what u mean?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to change the value of logfordb.pos I think you want to pass logfordb by ref. I suspect the value isn't changing and the second time you call this function you end up adding the same data again because the value outside of this scope isn't being changed just a local copy that the function sees (and then exists destroying references to the changes).

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterates through the entire logfordb every single time this is called.

You have three options:

1. At the end of this method, clear the logfordb entirely. (probably makes the most sense)
2. Add a starting position parameter, and let the calling code decide the position to start pushing the logfordb records into the database.
3. Add a "Stored" property to each record inside logfordb so that you can set it when that individual record has been stored and not push that record again.

Out of those, option 1 is probably your safest bet.